# How do you express Boolean negation in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, boolean-logic

In C and C++, the `!` negates the result:

```
if( !( a == b ) )
```

In Scheme, I found only `eq?`. How do I say "not equal"? Or we have to explicitly say

```
(eq? #f (eq? expr expr))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Scheme has a `not`, so you could do: `(not (eq? expr1 expr2))`

Answer (score -9):

Could you not have tried guessing?

```
(not #f) ==> #t
```

Comment: While I trust You meant no offense, the diplomacy of comments is sometimes hard to distinguish from demeaning remarks on the internet unless worded in a clear enough fashion.

Comment: I guessed it was (negate #f) ==> #t. As it did not work, I found this question helpful.

Comment: not #f does not means something is true, just that the program may have been unable to render a false.